# Formset: Key Error while submitting a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I followed a tutorial from this [blog](http://haineault.com/blog/155/). The code snippet is very simple and well described, but I got some `KeyError` in the second line.

```
context = self.get_context_data()
bookimage_form = context['bookimage_formset']
```

Can I get some explanations on that error? I have the concept of context and context processors. But I don't know what caused me this error.

Comment: `KeyError` raise when key is not present in dictionary

Comment: I tried that and too many other things. I even edited most of the code with my own but nothing seems to be right.

Comment: Without more code it's impossible to know where you've gone wrong. It's as hackaholic said, `KeyError` is raised when Python can't find the key `bookimage_formset` in your dict.

Answer (score 0):

There's clearly an error in that tutorial: the `get_context_data` method puts the formsets in `bookimage_form` and `bookpage_form` rather than the "_formset" version. Change either method appropriately.

Not that the template has yet another error, as it refers to `bookimages_formset` - with an s - which doesn't exist either. Quite careless, unfortunately, as the idea and presentation are good.